# ioctl check state of shift return error invalid argument

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ioctl

I try to run a sample code as below. The ioctl returned -1 and the error is "Invalid argument". What I know is that ioctl here is used to check the state of shift. Does ioctl return success when the shift is pressed? If not,  how do I know the shift is pressed by using ioctl?
Plus, it's under xterm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main()
{
    char shift_state;

    shift_state = 6;
    if (ioctl(0, TIOCLINUX, &shift_state) < 0) {
            perror("ioctl TIOCLINUX 6 (get shift state)");
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("%x\n", shift_state);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that only works under a linux virtual terminal (the one you switch to with Ctrl-Atl-Fn), not under xterm or any other pseudo-tty (eg. ssh or tmux). I wonder however why you got an EINVAL instead of ENODEV.